# Polymer 1.0: How to make paper-button change color on hover?

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

[This example](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-button?view=demo:demo/index.html) shows `paper-button` examples (in the last [4th] column [labeled colors]) that change color when the user hovers the mouse over it.

I can not find anywhere in the [Polymer 1.0 documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html) how to make this happen. Also, copying and pasting the source code for the element on [this page](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-button?view=demo:demo/index.html) doesn't work.

Can somebody please provide a working code example of how to make a Polymer 1.0 `paper-button` change color when the user hovers the mouse over it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your document's CSS:

```
paper-button:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: There can be no spaces between the `:` and the word `hover`.